# How to inflate android NavigationView with another menu dynamically during onClick?

Tags: android, material-design, navigationview

Hi I have a NavigationView and there is an imageview in the headerview of that NavigationView. When I click on the imageview , NavigationView should inflate another menu resource file and replace current menu like in PlayStore app.

I've tried this:

```
imgIndic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.e("Onclick","Arrow click");
        navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.second_menu);
    }
});
```

But when I click on the button, nothing happens! (Log Onclick is showing in the logcat)
How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try the following code

```
imgIndic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {      
        navView.getMenu().clear();
        navView.inflateMenu(R.menu.second_menu);
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Now you have given me solution for 2 times in a row! :)

Comment: oh yes I remember .. first one is on menuitem text color... lolz

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest to inflate just one menu with several groups and change the visibility of the groups. Simple and effective.

```
<group
    android:id="@+id/group_1"
    android:checkableBehavior="single"
    android:visible="false">
    ...
</group>

<group
    android:id="@+id/group_2"
    android:checkableBehavior="single"
    android:visible="true">
    ...
</group>
```

In your java code call

```
navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.group_1, true)
```

Comment: This one worked for the situation! +1 vote! Accepting @moinkhan 's answer for giving solution for inflating another menu dynamically. :)