# how to implement android side drawer tree structure menu?

Tags: android, sidebar

I am trying to implement Android sidebar. I know how to implement sliding sidebar with Drawer layout. The first pic is list and when I click on one of the item it shows the relevant list items. How to do this? please help me.

[image: First pic with side headings]

[image: List based on first pic heading]

Comment: I would use fragments inside your DrawerLayout. When the user clicks on an item in the list, you can change the fragment which is displayed.

Comment: Use ExpandableListView and ExpandableListAdapter in place of list.

Comment: @SHIVANIGARG That would work for the second "screen" assuming the "+" is a cue that the list expands when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear Whole Menu on Item Selection of **NavigationView**

```
    mainNavigationMenu_.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            //IT WILL HAPPEN ON BASIS OF ITEM ID OF MENU....
            navView.getMenu().clear();
            navView.inflateMenu(R.menu.second_menu);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

OR

you can change group of menu [Simple and effective way.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31203478/1318946)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the @Code-Apprentice comment.

Created a fragment for mainlist and another fragment for sublist. Once the mainlist item is selected, the mainlist fragment will be replaced by sublist with relevant data and added some fragment transaction animations.
it worked well.